# Is the Bridge Vertices feature in Blender 2.8x

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

Does Blender 2.8x have the "Bridge Vertices" feature like it had in Version 2.79 and older

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Do you mean Bridge Edge loops? It's in *Edge > Bridge edge loops*

Comment: NO! I meant "Bridge Vertices" . I didn't mention "Bridge Edge Loops".  Look at the later Blender versions that employ "Bridge Vertices" THAT's that I'm looking for in the newer Blender Versions.

Comment: Hello again :). My mistake. I'm afraid Martynas is right, and even Blender manual doesn't containt any *Bridge vertices* entry. The closest one is *Vertex Connect*.

Answer (score 3):

There is no feature called "Bridge Vertices" in Blender 2.79 even with any of the included add-ons enabled. I did not check all of the previous versions, but I suspect it was never there either and you must be mistaken.

In most versions of Blender you can connect two vertices by hitting <kbd>F</kbd> for Make Edge/Face. That includes versions 2.79, 2.80 and 2.81.

Comment: I see.. OK.. WIll give t try.. Hope it works for me. I'm looking to "Bridge" a Circle and a plane, and have them join together, exp.: a pipe flaring out to a square end.

Comment: This looks like what has been mentioned in the comments, "Bridge edge loops". You can then increase the number of cuts by unfolding the thingy in the lower left corner after calling the operator and changing the field

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.8 it is one feature which is similar to bridge function that you have mentioned RMB- LoopTools - Loft

You have to enable the LoopTools add-on in the preferences to use this feature.